# How to search for a .htaccess file with Windows?

Tags: windows, search, .htaccess, hidden

I am dealing with a massive nest of files and need to find a .htaccess file that is redirecting a single page in my website. I know how ridiculous this sounds: why not just check the directories the page is located within? But the problem is slightly more complicated than that. All I need though, is to search for every .htaccess file under the web folder. Trying a normal search doesn't allow me to select that type of file to search for, and searching for hidden files has just been (who knows why) ignoring the .htaccess files anyway. I can't download any new software to do this for me. but - there must be a way! Even if I could somehow list every file within a directory (and its subdirs) and then organize by file type and scroll down?

I could search for any file with the word "RewriteEngine" , but there are so many files, this would take forever.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

=/ notepad++ is not installed, and I don't have auth to install anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the commandline.

```
findstr /s RewriteEngine .htaccess
```

Searches the current directory and all sub directories for .htaccess files containing the string RewriteEngine.

Answer (score 1):

Try searching for files of the form: `*htaccess`

(spelled precisely like that in the search field)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using Notepad++. It has a 'Find in files...' option that you could specify the page that it's trying to redirect to, and you could have it check only in *.htaccess files.

Just a thought

Answer (score 0):

Search **All files and folders**, in **All or part of the filename**: put ".htaccess" including the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

in the command prompt:

for hidden files: dir /s /b /a:sh *.htaccess>C:\results.txt

for non-hidden files: dir /s /b *.htaccess>C:\results.txt

to search for "RewriteEngine" type dir /s /b *rewriteengine*

both of these will output the search results to a text file called "results"